# `Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.`

Tags: html, asp.net, path

I have tried the following navigation paths and still facing the same error.

> Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="~/Setup/Company.aspx" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>

<a runat="server" href="~/Setup/Company.aspx">Company</a>

<li><a href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Setup/Company.aspx") %>"><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i>Company</a></li>
```

I want to navigate to `Setup > Company.aspx`

[image: This is my project hierarchy]

[image]

Comment: This is a runtime error (when you click) or a compile time error (when you try to bring up the page)?

Comment: This is a runtime error